# How to transfer data of current item and create a new child cart on button click

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a way which will add item to cart by creating a child cart the in that child it will retrieve current username and then under that it will save all the details of added item

this is the code of the fragment in which cart button is available (course = description,email = price,purl = url of image)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;


public class descfragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    String name, course, email, purl;

    public descfragment() {

    }

    public descfragment(String name, String course, String email, String purl) {

        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
        this.email = email;
        this.purl = purl;
    }


    public static descfragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        descfragment fragment = new descfragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_descfragment, container, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity activity =(AppCompatActivity)getContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.wrapper,new recfragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });


        ImageView imageholder = view.findViewById(R.id.imageholder);
        TextView nameholder = view.findViewById(R.id.nameholder);
        TextView courseholder = view.findViewById(R.id.courseholder);
        TextView emailholder = view.findViewById(R.id.emailholder);
        Button cart = view.findViewById(R.id.cartt);
        TextView addItem =  view.findViewById(R.id.addIteam);
        TextView removeItem =  view.findViewById(R.id.removeItem);
        TextView quantity =  view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        final int[] totalquantity = {1};

        nameholder.setText(name);
        courseholder.setText(course);
        emailholder.setText(email);
        if (imageholder != null) {
            Glide.with(getContext()).load(purl).into(imageholder);
        }
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(purl).into(imageholder);

        //changing static getemail to int type


        //for openig cart

        //setting click on textview for increasing the quantity
        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(totalquantity[0] < 10){
                    totalquantity[0]++;
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(totalquantity[0]));
                }
            }
        });

        removeItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(totalquantity[0] > 1) {
                    totalquantity[0]--;
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(totalquantity[0]));
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.wrapper, new recfragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

this is the register activity code in this activity we have the username which needed to be retirived

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.foodcourt.MainActivity;
import com.example.foodcourt.R;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button5;

    //create obj of Databaserefrence to access firebase RealTime Database
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://url of firebase database/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final TextInputLayout nameLayout = findViewById(R.id.Name);
        final TextInputLayout phoneLayout = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        final TextInputLayout passwordLayout = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final TextInputLayout repassLayout = findViewById(R.id.repass);
        final Button signup = findViewById(R.id.sign);

        final EditText name = nameLayout.getEditText();
        final EditText phone = phoneLayout.getEditText();
        final EditText password = passwordLayout.getEditText();
        final EditText repass = repassLayout.getEditText();



        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //get data from editTexts into string

                final String nameTxt = name.getText().toString();
                final String phoneTxt = phone.getText().toString();
                final String passwordTxt = password.getText().toString();
                final String repassTxt = repass.getText().toString();

                //Check if user filled all details before sending data to firebase

                if (nameTxt.isEmpty() || phoneTxt.isEmpty() || passwordTxt.isEmpty() || repassTxt.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                //check if pass are matching

                else if (!passwordTxt.equals(repassTxt)) {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "PASSWORDS ARE NOT MATCHING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    databaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                            //check if phone number is registered before \

                            if (snapshot.hasChild(phoneTxt)) {
                                Toast.makeText(register.this, "Already registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                //sending data to Firebase
                                //using phoneNumbers
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(phoneTxt).child("name").setValue(nameTxt);
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(phoneTxt).child("phone").setValue(phoneTxt);
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(phoneTxt).child("password").setValue(passwordTxt);

                                Toast.makeText(register.this, "REGISTERED SUCCESFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(register.this, MainActivity.class));


                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I followed some tutorials but they were for firestore.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-firebase-part-1-4f305485e5d2) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireMag). Besides that, this part is related to the [schema](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-the-database-schemas-for-our-firebase-shopping-app-part-2-29f8bcac7acb).